# JavaScript code does not output the result on the first attempt

Tags: javascript

When I run the script (see below), the first attempt fails to get the result,

the "result" variable outputs "underfined"

```
var result;
Promise.resolve('information')
    .then(res => {return result=res})
    result;
```

Attempt #1

[image]

On the second attempt , the values are already assigned

[image]

Question: How can I expect to assign a value to the "result" variable, without using `setTimout` and `console.log`

Waiting with a While loop

```
var result;
var finito = false;
Promise.resolve('information')
    .then(res => {return result=res})

while(finito != true)
{
  if (result != undefined)
  {
    result;
    finito=true;
  }
}
```

---

**My question for Jay Surya:**

This code does not work

[image]

---

**My question for Azarro:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve

`Promise.resolve` returns a promise. If it's accompanied by a `.then`, it'll follow up on the .then() asynchronously (almost immediately, emphasis on **almost**) and resolve as a Promise.

If you want result to get the actual value then you'll have to either use **await** in order to force the code to act synchronously and wait on the promise's value.

```
async function someWrappedFunction() {
const result = await Promise.resolve('information');
}
```

Alternatively, you can move your code inside the `.then` block of Promise so that you're guaranteed a value in there.

Edit:
Can you try the following:

```
var result;
var finito = false;
var result = await Promise.resolve('information');

while(finito != true)
{
  if (result != undefined)
  {
    result;
    finito=true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please see above i added new addition, your script does not work, please help

Comment: You forgot the `function` keyword!

Comment: Whoops, thanks Mike! Hopping between languages heh

Comment: @Csharp_cowboy the function keyword was missing, try it again it should work :)

Comment: @Azarro, I added image question above, please take a look

Comment: @Csharp_cowboy the output is `true` because `finito=true` is the last statement that is executed, hence the output shown to you is the value of finito. If you type result at the end, you'll see the value of `result` instead

Comment: @Azarro, Why its impossible to do this only with Promises without using async/await?

Comment: So if you did `var result; Promise.resolve('information').then((data) => result = data);` the reason this doesn't work is because of the infinite while loop. Promises with `thens` are guaranteed to run asynchronously; i.e. all the code after the Promise, such as the while loop, you can assume will be run first before asynchronous promises are resolved. But the promise can only execute its `then` block once the while loop has resolved. Since the while loop never yields, it'll be infinite in this case, never yielding, and thus not allowing the Promise's `then(..)` to run in the example above.

Comment: That explanation is also why in your first first code block in the original question, result was initially undefined on the first attempt. It's because the `.then(...)` is executed AFTER the `result;` statement is executed because promises are asynchronous.

Comment: @Azarro, could you please help me, how to output result of "b" ```function a1(callback) {
        var a = 2 + 2;
        console.log(a);
        callback();
  }

async function a2() {
    let b = 2 + 3;
    await b;
}

a1(a2);```

Comment: You need to make a1 an async function as well and do `return await callback()`. Then in a2, you need to do `return await b`

Comment: @Azarro, it works! thank you brother! if i want to output the result of "a" also, how can i do? ```async function a1(callback) {
        var a = 2 + 2;
        return await a;
        return await callback();
  }

async function a2() {
    var b = 2 + 3;
    return await b;
}

a1(a2);```

Comment: @Azarro, please help me with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72203250/javascript-how-to-execute-firstpromise-before-secondpromise/72203286#72203286

Answer (score 1):

Best Solution for this is to use async-await, Since you seem to need `result` for further operations. If you still want to use .then() approach, you will have to move your `var result` and all the subsequent steps which need `result`, into the `.then()`

```
Promise.resolve('information').then(res=>{
var result = res;
var finito=true;
//all that follows

})
```

But alternatively if you use async-await,

```
var result;
var finito = false;
result = await Promise.resolve('information');//the lines below will not be executed, until this promise resolves

while(finito != true)
{
  if (result != undefined)
  {
    result;
    finito=true;
  }
}
```

Ofcourse, await can only be used inside a function marked as async.

Comment: ...or in a module.

Comment: Why its impossible to do this with Promise?

Comment: @Jay Surya, I added image question above, please take a look