# JavaScript How to execute firstPromise before secondPromise

Tags: javascript, promise

This might seem a silly question, but I am a newbie in this topic. In the script below i have two promises. By now "secondPromise" executing first, and then executing "firstPromise". Cuz in the "secondPromise" i set less time. But how to execute "firstPromise" first, after finished that, start executing the "secondPromise"?
How to rewrite the script below

```
(async function()
{
//var final = new Array();
var final;
const firstPromise = new Promise(
function(resolve)
{
    let result = 2 + 2;
    resolve(result);
    setTimeout(() => console.log("please show me first"), 2000);
});
const secondPromise = new Promise(
function(resolve)
{
    let result2 = 0;
    resolve(result2 + 1);
    setTimeout(() => console.log("please show me second"), 1000);
});
var myP = Promise.all([firstPromise, secondPromise]).then((values) => {
    return values[0]+values[1];
  });
return myP;
})();
```

```js
(async function()
{
//var final = new Array();
var final;
const firstPromise = new Promise(
function(resolve)
{
    let result = 2 + 2;
    resolve(result);
    setTimeout(() => console.log("please show me first"), 2000);
});

const secondPromise = new Promise(
function(resolve)
{
    let result2 = 0;
    resolve(result2 + 1);
    setTimeout(() => console.log("please show me second"), 1000);
});

var myP = Promise.all([firstPromise, secondPromise]).then((values) => {
    return values[0]+values[1];
  });
return myP;
})();
```

Comment: Is this type of indentation and line separation how you actually write your code?  If not, please fix the formatting here to match how you actually write code.  If so, I'm having a heck of a time reading your chosen code formatting.

Comment: Also, why are you wrapping code into an `async` IIFE when there's no use of `await` anywhere?

Comment: Use `firstPromise.then(firstValue => { /* create second promise in here */ })` instead of constructing both of them right away (and using `Promise.all`)

Answer (score 1):

[Quentin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72203286/1426891) is correct: the function you pass to `new Promise` happens immediately. However: because you already have this in an `async` function, you can `await` Promises within it. This pauses the `async` function until the Promise resolves, so unlike your function with `Promise.all` that waits for your explicit `new Promise` Promises in parallel, my function waits for those Promises serially.

Furthermore, if you want the `new Promise` constructions you wrote to wait for the action in `setTimeout`, you need to wait and call the `resolve` method within the callback that `setTimeout` calls, not outside them as you have it.

```js
console.log("start");
(async function () {
    const firstValue = await new Promise(
        //             ^^^^^
        function (resolve) {
            let result = 2 + 2;
            setTimeout(() => {
                console.log("please show me first");
                resolve(result);  // Promise resolves after 2000ms
            }, 2000);
        });

    const secondValue = await new Promise(
        //              ^^^^^
        function (resolve) {
            let result2 = 0;
            setTimeout(() => {
                console.log("please show me second");
                resolve(result2 + 1);
            }, 1000);
        });
    // These are values, not promises, because you await them.
    // However, the async function still returns a Promise, because
    // "async" covers the asynchronicity of the Promises you await.
    return firstValue + secondValue;
})().then(x => console.log(x));  // or .then(console.log)
```

Comment: Without using async/await i cant do this?

Comment: @Csharp_cowboy You can, by putting the second promise in the `then` of the first promise, but your question had `async` in it and it's not idiomatic to mix `async` and `then` in the same function. Generally you can do anything with `then` that you can do with `async`, but I find `async` is often more readable than a lot of chained `then` calls.

Answer (score -1):

You can't execute a promise.

You can execute a function.

If you pass a function to a Promise constructor, then it will be executed (by the Promise constructor) immediately.

There is no way to delay the execution of a function passed to a Promise constructor.

You could wrap your calls to `new Promise` in functions, and then only call the second function when the first promise is resolved.

(Note, however, that in your examples the calls to `setTimeout` happen *after* the `resolve` function is called).